# std::string::find returns wrong answer

Tags: c++, find, hex, stdstring

There are some posts concerning std::string::find (like [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299605/problem-with-stdstringfind) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488093/stdstringfind-always-returns-stringnpos-even)) but I have a somewhat different situation:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string haystack = "ab\\x10c\200\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00";
    std::string needle   = "\\x00";

    printf("first index is %d\n",(int) haystack.find(needle));

    return 0;
}
```

According to the values I'm wondering why 8 is returned:

I guess "\200" is counted as 1 character (?)
Can I make `find` treat `"\\x10"` as 1 character too?

Comment: ques is not clear

Comment: how do haystack and needle defined? and how did you initialize them?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @drorco, they are parameters sent to some function ... this line is from the body of the function ...

Comment: then what is the signature of that function? and how do you call it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code leaves quite some room for interpretation and guessing

Comment: I've fixed the example to be self contained and reproducible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All works properly

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | \ | x | 1 | 0 | c | \200 | \ | x | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |   7  | 8 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+
```

`\\` becomes one char `\`. It seems you wanted `\xNN` with one `\`.

Even if you replace `\\` with `\` in the literal string, it will not work, since the first `\x00` will be treated as terminating zero and other chars after it will be ignored. I guess that the initialization of strings should be like below:

```
std::string haystack = {'a', 'b', '\x10', 'c', '\200', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00'};
std::string needle   = {'\x00'};
```

The program will output 5.

Answer (score 1):

`\200` *is* 1 character. See the [list of escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). I've included the relevant ones here:

```
Escape sequence    Description                    Representation
\\                 backslash                      byte 0x5c in ASCII encoding
\nnn               arbitrary octal value          byte nnn
\xnn               arbitrary hexadecimal value    byte nn
```

`\200` is a single character with the value 128 (200 in octal is 128 in decimal).

`\\x10` is 4 characters: `\\` ( a backslash), `x`, `1`, and `0`. If you want it as a single character then don't escape the backslash - `\x10` is a single character with the value 16 (10 in hexadecimal is 16 in decimal).

Answer (score 0):

`\200` is one of the **Zero Width Non Joiner**. That is an unicode character that is encoded in UTF-8.

e.g-

```
0x2e, 0x80, 0x8c (or in base 8, \342, \200, \214)
```

Here is how your string is indexed:

0 a
1 b
2 \
3 x
4 1
5 0
6 c
7 �
8 \
9 x
10 0
11 0
12 \
13 x
14 0
15 0
16 \
17 x
18 0
19 0
20 \
21 x
22 0
23 0

See the `7th` index. That will clear your doubt.

If you want to read `\\x10` as a single char, then use `\x10` which will treat it as a hexadecimal number.